# DOM Element Load Time Benchmarking

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, benchmarking, webdriver-io, web-frontend

I'd like to benchmark my web application. Specifically I'd like to measure the load time of a particular DOM element.

I can use webdriver's [wait for visible](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html) to measure how long a an element took to load and save the result somewhere. However I'd also like to measure concurrency and other factors.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

While I love WebdriverIO, I would recommend using a tool other than it for benchmarking. WebdriverIO uses HTTP requests to send commands to Selenium, and because of that isn't the most performant thing. Your stats could be way off simply because the request from WebdriverIO to Selenium takes longer than usual.

I'd suggest using a tool a little "closer to the metal", possibly [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)